# is there any model and database generation with column in laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

in ruby on rails, we can do

`rails generate model note title body:text`

to create:

1. model called `Note`
2. table called `notes`
3. column in notes table with name `title` as `string`
4. column in notes table with name `body` as `text`

is there any possible way to do this in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel we have `artisan` which has a lot of commands for performing common tasks such as `Model`, `Controller` and `migration` generation.

For your specific case you could do something like the following:

```
php artisan make:model Note -mc
```

The above would create a `model` in `app/Models`. The `-mc` flags tell `artisan` to also make a `migration` in the `database/migrations` directory and a `controller` in the `app/Http/Controllers` directory.

To add fields for your `Note` model, you will need to do that yourself in the migration file that was generated. Then you can use `php artisan migrate` to execute the new migration.

For other commands of `artisan`, just type `php artisan` in your console and you'll see a full list of commands.

Comment: so the answer is no?

Comment: @ArifIkhsanudin Correct. There is no exact replacement for that rails command.

Comment: that just so sad